# Batch File - for /F loop - read multiple Variables

Tags: batch-file

I need to load different numeric values from external config.txt file and write them to %variables% in batch file. Example - config.txt file should looks as following:

```
==================== 
Setting1=1 
Setting2=0 
Setting3=1 
====================
```

I need to assign first value (1) lets say into variable %1%, second value (0) into variable %2% and so on.

Could you please help me how to do this?

### Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

```
@echo off&setlocal
for /f %%i in (config.txt) do set "%%i" 2>nul
set "setting"
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know how many variables there will be? If you don't then go with Endoro's answer. If you do know how many variables there will be and you want to set them to a custom name you could do this:

```
@echo off
< config.txt (
set /p var1=
set /p var2=
set /p var3=
)
echo %var1%
echo %var2%
echo %var3%
pause
```

You shouldn't use %1% or plain numbers for variables, it can mess it up.

If config.txt had those '=' signs then you would have to skip add two more lines for the var's.

The reason you should use this for custom variables is because you could name the variables by there specific meaning which may make it easier to remember when coding.

Ex.

```
@echo off
< config.txt (
set /p name=
set /p pizza=
set /p car=
)
echo %name%
echo %pizza%
echo %car%
pause
```